# Prevent antd component from rerender

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-query

I have an antd collapse component which is wrapped by react-query and I'm enabling `refetchInterval` in my query, so the issue is that antd Collapse component is restored to its initial state(closed) automatically after opening when the time which I gave to `RefetchInterval` is set,  so is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the key of the **Collapse.Panel** in the `defaultActiveKey` of the **Collapse** component.

```
<Collapse  defaultActiveKey={['1']}>
    <Collapse.Panel header="panel1" key="1">
        //some components
    </Collapse.Panel>
</Collapse>
```

**OR**
You can use a state and pass it on the `activeKey` props of the **Collapse**.

For more information: https://ant.design/components/collapse/#API